# adding new support library redlines the current library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

My gradle file

```
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

  minSdkVersion 17
  targetSdkVersion 25

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

adding `'compile com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0` causes the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` to be redlined
  `` in my code and i want to use the `CardView` feature in my app and using only the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` didnt do the work

what can i do to avoid using libraries that conflicts each other in my code and does it mean ?

The error message i received when i play my mouse on the red line

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.4.0, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to add `CardView` version which is greater than your `appcompat` version. So in order to fix this you need to use the same version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: so i need to add the same version and a version which is not greater than my  `appcompat` anytime i want to add new support library right?

Comment: Yes it shouldn't exceed more than the `appcompat` version

Comment: but will trhis work for all types of support library that exist in android ecosystem? or i dont have any problem if assuming i want to use the v4- libraries?